# Uint8Array is too slowly on Chrome

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, buffer, uint8array

I want to optimize the speed performance of using Uint8Array. Now it takes about 3121.5 ms to work with 4mb size file in Google Chrome. Although, the same operation takes 144 ms on Firefox. What I can do with it?

```
    stringToBuffer: function(str) {
            const arr = str.split(',');
            const view = new Uint8Array(arr);
            return view.buffer;
},
```

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: Added the code ->

Comment: String#split is probably just [too slow](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=7103). Try ```const arr = JSON.parse(`[${str}]`);```

Comment: Yes, it helps. It's 689.8 ms now. But maybe I can do something else with it?

Comment: 1) Change the way the data is stored from comma-separated numbers to direct binary format so you can do fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer, 2) or run this function in a Web Worker so it doesn't block UI.

Comment: ok, thank you for help